# Calling form that runs in a loop from a command button

Tags: forms, excel, loops, vba

I want to run a form called PostFlight, from a command button on a spreadsheet, the form will run for a number of entry cycles.

So currently I have a commandbutton click that calls the form called PostFlight successfully.

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Counter = 0
    BatteryAmp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is battery Amps?")
        Range("AC1").Value = BatteryAmp
    BatteryCounter = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many batteries?")
        Range("AA204").Value = BatteryCounter
PostFlight.Show
End Sub`

The form called Postflight works exactly as I want it to as a standalone form.

My question is where to place the loop and where to define the variables of that loop.

I know that I want to define a Counter as an Integer and the loop must run until it reaches the BatteryCounter value. But where to place the loop?

Do I place it in the declarations alongside the Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

OR

Do I place it in the form code and if I place it in the form code, does it make a difference as to where in the code I place the loop.

I have tried to increment and display a counter in the code of the form

```
Counter = Counter + 1
Range("AA205").Value = Counter
```

But it does not work for some or other reason.

Hopefully you are able to assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This needs one or additional tags to reach the right audience. Is it VBA? Vb.net?

Comment: do you want the Form to Show itself for each instance of the counter? Or do you want to manipulate objects in the form for each counter?

Comment: I want to have the form show in each instance.
eg. I want to enter a variable amount for the amount of times I want to enter the details, enter instance 1 details, post these details to the spreadsheet, the form clears and follows again for the initial variable amount of form entries.
My form does exactly that and clears and allows entry after I hit the enter button, but I want to restrict the amount of times the entry form appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, this should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Counter as Integer

    BatteryAmp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is battery Amps?")
        Range("AC1").Value = BatteryAmp
    BatteryCounter = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many batteries?")
        Range("AA204").Value = BatteryCounter

    For Counter = 1 to BatteryCounter
        PostFlight.Show
    Next

End Sub
```

I did a mini-test with this code and it worked. However, you will need to make sure the button on your Form that fills the cells with entries has the line `PostFlight.Hide` after it finishes filling the cells, or after the Form is done doing everything you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you very much
It was the Postflight.Hide that I did not have in my code that caused the form to keep popping up after every data entry.
Not sure why the variable indicators that I put on my spreadsheet to show how the variables change is not showing the changes correctly but this is not a big deal as the code is working and I did that as a debugging exercise.
Thanks again.